# proteinbertからEmbeddingを取得する方法について

Tags: python, 機械学習, 自然言語処理

タンパク質言語モデルであるproteinberthttps://github.com/nadavbra/protein_bert
を用いて入力したアミノ酸配列のEmbeddingを取得する方法が知りたいです。
fine-tuningを行わずに取得したEmbeddingを学習に用いたいです。
詳しい方、よろしければご教授ください。

Comment: 「機械学習もプログラミングも初心者のためよくわかりません」だと、第三者はどこから説明したらいいのかが分からない気がします。